# Восстановить матрицу

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы, scipy

Есть матрица  Y 20х20. Она бинарная. К ней применяют функцию "step"  и получается другая бинарная матрица  X 20х20.

Задача: Мы знаем только матрицу Х. Мы знаем функцию, по которой получили матрицу Х. Нам надо предсказать Y' как можно лучше. Метрика MSE. Известно: что Y' будет состоять из вещественных чисел от 0 до 1.

Как можно это сделать?  Пытался генерировать  любую  бинарную матрицу, применять функцию. Но ничего толкового не выходит. Не понимаю тот факт, как получаются вещественные числа  в предсказанной матрице.
P.S. функция сложная - по обратному пути не пройти. Нельзя использовать методы машинного обучения
Спасибо за подсказу и помощь

```
def step(X):
    n = X.shape[0]
    W = convolve2d(X, np.ones((3, 3)), mode='same', boundary='wrap') - X
    a = np.tile(np.floor(np.arange(n) / (n / 3)) + 1, (n, 1))
    b =  a.T + 1
    a, b = np.minimum(a, b), np.maximum(a, b)
    gamma = (a + b) / 2
    return ((W <= b)&(W >= gamma)) | (X & (W >= a)& (W <= gamma))
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: если нельзя использовать машинное обучение, зачем вы поставили метку машинное обучение ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs, исправил

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо за отклик. Добавил скрин с формой ввода/вывода

Comment: Исправьте `beta =  a.T + 1` на `b =  a.T + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что a, b, gamma -константы. W - перемешивает информацию только из 9 соседних ячеек исходной матрицы.

алгоритм (1): перебор локальных подмножеств

Берем миноры размера 4x4 в исходной матрице, перебираем все комбинации из 16 бит. Смотрим какие комбинации приводят к правильному минору 2x2 в результирующией матрице (который зависит только от изменяемых нами бит). Если во всех "правильных" комбинациях какой-то бит всегда в одном и том же значении, значит значение этого бита в исходной матрице мы становили точно. При подборе следующих квадратов 4x4, биты значения которых установленны - уже не трогаем.

Можно попробовать с квадратами 3x3 или 5x5. Но 3x3 - можно не найти решение, а 5x5 - больше трудозатраты.

Идеологически, алгоритм напоминает бота для игры в сапера.
Теоретически, алгоритм должен найти точное значение матрицы Y, если это вообще возможно. И, да, он чрезвычайно трудозатратен.

способ (2): Метод Монте-Карло (или роевой метод поиска минимума)

Запоминаем матрицу вероятностей P. (Физически это вероятность, что в исходной матрице на заданном месте стоит 1.). Первоначально, матрица заполнена 0.5.

1. Генерируем случайную матрицу Yi, в соответствии с вероятностями P.
2. `Xi = step(Yi)`
3. Если Xi - лучше чем предудущая лучшая матрица - то запоминаем ее.
4. Сравниваем ячейки Xi и X. Растягиваем информацию для об успехе / не успехе на соседние ячейки (от которых завист успех в этой ячейке). `Wins=convolve2d( ( Xi==X )*2. -1., np.ones((3, 3)), mode='same', boundary='wrap')`
5. Поправляем вероятность P: увеличиваем вероятность тех битиков, которые привели к успеху и наоборот.  `P+=Wins*Xi*0.01`
6. Поправляем P, так чтобы значения оставались в интервале [0., 1.]

Повторяем п.1-6 достаточное число раз.

Comment: за идею спасибо. Но не совсем понимаю, как смогу получить на выходе вещественные числа.  Опишу логику, как я понял.  Берем минор 4х4( пусть 1-ый вариант это будут все нули), прогоняем через функцию, сравниваем  с минором 2х2 в моей матрице X.  И так по всем возможным комбинациям .Правильно ли понимаю, что там где, что-то не будет сходится, я уже или усредняю или придумываю что-то, отсюда и берутся вещественные числа. Вот только не много я в шоке. Для матрицы 2х2 -это 16 вариантов. Плюс прогонять по всей матрице 20х20. А еще в выборке 50к матриц)

Comment: @Astraz Числа берутся  из преобразование `bool->int->float`.   Вообще-то предложенный алгоритм предполагает что мы хотим найти единственное и точное решение (т.е абсолютный минимум в любой разумной метреке). И да, он жутко не производительный. Про 50к матриц в исходной постановке задачи ничего небыло.

Comment: Можно чуть по подробнее про bool->int->float. Все же остается не ясно для меня, появление вещественного числа. Сенк

Comment: @Astraz функция step, конечно, возвращает матрицу из bool-ов. Но во всех математических операциях с bool, (сложение, умножение) он преобразуеся в число True->1, False->0.

Comment: это я понимаю, просто подумал не о том, спасибо. Я просто не понимаю, даже идя по тому алгоритму, что вы предложили, на каком этапе у меня сгенерируется допустим в матрице Y' [0][1] допустим 0.754... Ведь функция step будет генерировать на выходе (return)  bool и  и матрицу, которую я ей падам Y'. Так как в этой Y' появится вещественное число. Плюс по алгоритму с минором мы всегда сопоставляем  бинарные числа против бинарных. Сенк

Comment: Спасибо за обновление ответа.

Comment: @Astraz в 1-м алгоритме `Yi[0][1] ==0.754` не появится ни на каком этапе. У нас есть две матрицы: Yi -из нулей и единиц. И матрица (пусть будет  S), которая будет хранить нашили ли мы точное значение для ячейки, или нет. Можно считать, что у нас есть три состояния ячейки: 0/1/unknown, но подходящего типа данных нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если что я тут код написал с "генетическим" перебором - делаем случайную матрицу и понемногу её мутируем в ожидании лучшего результата. И так много раз. Результат не очень и код грязноват, ошибка к нулю не сходится, но может пользуясь знанием из [ответа Chorkov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437416/260769) кто-то более правильную мутацию сделает. Мне просто некогда сейчас.

Код инициализации:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

def step(X):
    n = X.shape[0]
    W = convolve2d(X, np.ones((3, 3)), mode='same', boundary='wrap') - X
    a = np.tile(np.floor(np.arange(n) / (n / 3)) + 1, (n, 1))
    b =  a.T + 1
    a, b = np.minimum(a, b), np.maximum(a, b)
    gamma = (a + b) / 2
    return (((W <= b)&(W >= gamma)) | (X.astype(bool) & (W >= a)& (W <= gamma))).astype(int)

n = 20
Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, n))
X = step(Y)
```

Код с выбором лучших мутаций:

```py
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

YY = None
MSE_ = n*n
r = tqdm(range(100))
for z in r:
    Y1 = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, n))
    MSE = n*n
    t = tqdm(range(10_000), leave=False)
    for i in t:
        Y2 = Y1.copy()
        for j in range(np.random.randint(1, n+1)):
            x, y = np.random.randint(0, n, 2)
            Y2[x,y] = 1 - Y2[x, y]
        X2 = step(Y2)
        MSE1 = ((X2-X)**2).sum()/n/n
        if MSE1 < MSE:
            MSE = MSE1
            Y1 = Y2
            t.set_description(f'{MSE:.2f}')
    if MSE < MSE_:
        MSE_ = MSE
        YY = Y1
        r.set_description(f'{MSE_:.2f}')
```

Лучше чем `0.11` так не получилось, если я вообще правильно `MSE` считаю.